# PHP session doesn't update when user logs ou

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website in php which uses mySQL to create accounts and allow users to log in and log out. Everything is working fine. When the users logs in, it changes their ENUM value, "loggedin" to 1 meaning they are logged in. But when they log out, it doesnt change to 0. I have the logout hyperlinking to a logout php and this is the code of that logout php.

```
<?php // Create connection include_once 'credentials.php';

$conn = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database); // Check connection if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

 }else{   

session_start();

session_destroy(); $sql = ("UPDATE users SET loggedin = '0' WHERE id = '$userid'");
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql); header("Location: ../index.php"); exit; }

?>
```

but it doesnt seem to be working. Also, on the logged in one, when the user logs in the first time, the loggedin status is changed in mySQL but the website does not show it unless the user logs out, then back in again.

Comment: I think your `$userid` variable is missing from your logout script

Comment: This approach won't be fun long-term. Some users will close the page without logging out, and you'll have 1s where you should have 0s.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. This has many dangerous [SQL injection vulnerabilities](http://bobby-tables.com/) since you didn’t [properly escape values](http://bobby-tables.com/php). This code allows *anyone* to get *anything* from your site. **DO NOT** write your own authentication system. Any [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) built-in.

Answer (score -1):

You have to check your update query in mysql application (eg: phpmyadmin) for making sure that query runs well.
Then try to remove `( )` of this line `$sql = ("UPDATE users SET loggedin = '0' WHERE id = '$userid'");` so like this `$sql = "UPDATE users SET loggedin = '0' WHERE id = '$userid'";`
For the last, make sure the path of header location is right.
Hopefully it will be success :)

Comment: The parentheses are fine. Unnecessary, but fine.

Comment: @ceejayoz The parens look like some kind of cargo-cult programming practice.